# ID of button changes, but document.ready function calls previous value's method

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, events, express

I'm writing a simple single page application with Express.js. At the bottom of the page is a form, and this form is used to add users to a table, or to update a specific user. The 'submit' button will have a different function depending on the ID of the button at the time it is pressed.

Inside my document.ready function, I have 2 lines of interest:

```
$('#btnAddUser').on('click', addUser);
$('#btnUpdateUser').on('click', updateUser);
```

I also have methods that change the value of this id from #btnAddUser to #btnUpdateUser, and vice versa. I can get the ID to change. The issue is that the document.ready function doesn't seem to consider these changes.

For instance, the app starts out with the id #btnAddUser. Then I change it to have the Id #updateUser, and I can see that this works. When I press the button, though, the addUser method fires instead of the updateUser method, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Changing the id of markup is not the right approach here. Even though technically it can be done but I would suggest keep two buttons.

Comment: The `document.ready` function only runs when the page is loaded. It doesn't keep running over and over. Your problem pretty much has nothing to do with `document.ready`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointy's answer should work, but this is an [X->Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't be trying to toggle functionality by changing an element's ID.

Instead, store a value somewhere that says what the button should do, and then use that. You could use a `data-*` attribute on the button if you want:

```html
<!-- Dynamically change  data-action  and  value  as needed -->
<input id="btnUserAction" type="button" data-action="add" value="Add" />
```

```js
$('#btnUserAction').on('click', function (e) {
    var action = ($(this).data("action") === "add") ? addUser : updateUser;

    action.call(this, e);
});
```

Alternatively, you could have two separate buttons and show/hide them. Either approach should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the effect you want by using event delegation to set up the handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnAddUser', addUser);
$(document).on('click', '#btnUpdateUser', updateUser);
```

By doing it that way, you defer the inspection of the element until the time a "click" actually happens. With your code, the elements were located at the time the handlers were assigned. After that, it doesn't matter what the "id" value is because the handler is directly associated with the DOM node (via an internal map that jQuery maintains).

Answer (score 2):

This won't work, because the click event is assigned one time when ready function executes. I think the better way is to have two buttons and show/hide them instead of changing the id.
Another way would be to store the action you want in an attribute:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr("data-action");
    if(action == "do_this")
    // ...
});
```

And for changing the action:

```
$('#mybutton').attr("data-action", "do_this");
```